# Netbeans. How to find out referenced libraries (not included in a project code)?

Tags: netbeans, clone, libraries

I have a netbeans project: java Web Application.

Some libraries in the project are'nt included in code directory. e.g.

....netbeans\7.1\var\cache\index\s717\java\14\gensrc\javax\mail\MimeMessage

so when I clone the project in other machine the library isnt found, because the netbeans directory is different. Is there a tool that check it? Maybe a netbeans plugin. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try right-clicking on the Libraries in your Netbeans Project Browser, and selecting "Add JAR/Folder". From there, navigate to the JAR you want, and select "Reference as Relative Path".

[image: Select Relative Path]

Comment: It works. I will be careful using libraries and I think is better to include them in a project always. Tks gobernador!

Comment: My pleasure! Be sure to mark this answer as accepted so others coming by can see that this is a solution to their problem.